# jQuery swipeleft and swiperight

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a little slider box that you can slick the forward and back arrows to scroll through the content. But I wanted to add swipe functionality to it, and this is my first time messing with any of the swipe stuff so im a bit lost, below is the code I was playing with;

```
//script for sliders

var currentlyAnimating = false;

$('.box-left').click(slideleft);
$( ".r-wide-box" ).on( "swipeleft", slideleft);

$('.box-right, .phone-next-serv').click(slideright);
$( ".r-wide-box" ).on( "swiperight", slideright);

  function slideleft ( ){
     var width = $(".wide-box > .row-fluid-wrapper").width();
    if (currentlyAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    currentlyAnimating = true;
    $('.wide-box > .row-fluid-wrapper:last').prependTo('.wide-box');
    $('.wide-box').css('left', -width);

    $('.wide-box').animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        $('.wide-box').css('left', '0px');

        currentlyAnimating = false;
    });

  }


  function slideright ( ){
    var width = $(".wide-box > .row-fluid-wrapper").width();
    if (currentlyAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    currentlyAnimating = true;

    $('.wide-box').animate({
        left: -width
    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
        $('.wide-box').css('left', '0px');
        $('.wide-box > .row-fluid-wrapper:first').appendTo('.wide-box');
        currentlyAnimating = false;
    });


};
```

Comment: Did you make sure to add the jquery mobile library? http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

Comment: I had not, thanks. It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JQuery has not defined events for mobile devices like swipe, touch, etc.

Ideally, these events are required when one is developing mobile apps or is supporting responsive layout design. Only then these events are required. So, it has been defined only in JQuery mobile and not the jQuery.

Adding jquery mobile might do the trick, but I would suggest NOT to add it, only to support the swipe events as jQuery mobile has been designed for totally a different purpose i.e. for developing mobile apps by providing predefined attributes for pages, header, etc.

Just googling can provide one with some good libraries that support touch events.

Comment: Indeed, after adding jquery mobile a bunch of strange things started happening to my layout, but I will continue looking into other library's. Thank you.

Comment: I know that I was late, but maybe for others. You can build your own jquery mobile only with the touch support: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to add the jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```